# Cosmos DB: Collection exists, but throwing a 410 GONE httpstatus code

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I some code that is checking if a collection exists when my application starts up.

however, the code to check:

```
await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, collectionId));
```

is throwing a DocumentClientException with a 410 GONE http status code.

however, when I use my data explorer, I see that the collection with the collectionId I provided DOES exist. Further, I have attempted the following in a test:

```
try
{
    await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, collectionId));
}
catch (DocumentClientException e)
{

    if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound || e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Gone)
    {
        var collection = new DocumentCollection { Id = collectionId, ResourceId = collectionId };
        await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
            UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(DatabaseId),
            collection,
            new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 1000 });
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

This code still throws the DocumentClientException with the 410 status code. However when I attempt to create the document collection, it is failing with `Resource with specified id or name already exists`

am I doing my search incorrectly? I did create the collection manually, so maybe the collectionID is different, but seems strange I cannot set the document collection ID outside of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `DocumentCollectionQuery` to check whether it exists or not. `ReadDocumentCollectionAsync` is not quite the same.

You can check how it is done in Cosmosnaut's [CosmosCollectionCreator.cs](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut/blob/f77af24b459e35e9745e4d91f6774feb73c5a8e8/src/Cosmonaut/Storage/CosmosCollectionCreator.cs).

Just query using

```
var collection = _documentClient
            .CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(database.SelfLink)
            .ToArray()
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == collectionName);
```

and then create it with

```
collection = await _documentClient.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(database.SelfLink, collection, new RequestOptions
        {
            OfferThroughput = collectionThroughput
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is way better to verify this way. not really sure why the other way no longer works... it used to throw a 404 not found, but this whole exists, but says its gone is weird...